# Where can I find a ZwCreateFile example for C++?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, serial-port

I am looking for an example to read an already opened COM port, the only thing that I have found is an application called PORTMON that refers to a method called `ZwCreateFile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

codeproject.com - is a nice site for looking examples.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/chaiyasit_t.aspx

**edit:**
msdn have information too
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363424.aspx